# jQuery fade transition causes weird flicker when fading into next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with my jQuery code where whenever I transition to another html file in my repository, there is this subtle flicker that happens before the next page transitions in.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn(200);
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $link = $(this).attr("href");
        $("body").fadeOut(200,function(){
          window.location =  $link; 
        });
    });
 });
```

I'm really not sure how to solve it and could use some help in figuring out...thanks!

Comment: New page takes time to load. No way to troubleshoot this based on what is shown or what is known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this behavior, first take a look at how `$(document).ready` works in jQuery:

> The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been
>   loaded.

The code inside `$(document).ready` - and thus, the `hide()` function - gets executed once the page has already been rendered, naturally causing a noticeable flicker before hiding the `body` all of sudden and then fading it in.

One way to solve this issue could be by adding some CSS and approaching the problem from a different angle.

First, you could add a class, ex. `.faded-out` to the `body` element in HTML.

The following CSS code would need to be added:

```
body{
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.faded-out{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

(the `200ms` corresponds to `200` in jQuery; `ease-in-out` corresponds to default animation timing function in jQuery, `swing`)

Then, you could remove `.faded-out` class from `body` inside of `$(document).ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').removeClass("faded-out");
    ...your remaining code
    });
 });
```

Perceived effect should be the same, minus the flicker, as the body is faded out before `$(document).ready` gets called.